# How to disable backlit keyboard in Ubuntu 20.04 (Dell Latitude)

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, dell, keyboard-backlight

I would like to disable the keyboard backlight on a Dell Latitude E5570.

According to [the official documentation](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-ie/sln153665/how-to-turn-off-or-on-and-troubleshoot-the-backlit-keyboard-on-your-dell-notebook-computer?lang=en) this should be possible by selecting "disable" for the corresponding BIOS parameter. I did this several times but the BIOS setting automatically goes back on every time I boot to Ubuntu.

I found these old bug reports which appear to be related, but I don't know if these still apply for 20.04:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/dell-sputnik/+bug/1510344
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/dell-sputnik/+bug/1583861

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Space Bar</kbd>. <kbd>Fn</kbd> is the key between the <kbd>windows key</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>.

This is the shortcut for toggling the backlight on the keyboard for my Lenovo laptop. It might be the same for Dell.

Edit: For the Dell Latitude, the toggle command is <kbd>Fn</kbd> +  <kbd>F10</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but actually what I would like is to disable it completely, not having to turn it off at every boot.

Comment: In my case, my laptop remembers the last toggle, and keeps it that way. So if you toggle it off, it will probably stay off.

Comment: Oh you're right! I was so focused on the BIOS setting not working that I missed this simple thing. Thanks a lot, that solves it indeed. For anyone reading this later, the equivalent key on Dell Latitude is Fn + F10.

Comment: Glad I could help :)